# Capture data on request timeout

Tags: asp.net, web-services, file-upload, timeout, ashx

I'm getting a lot of timeouts on an ashx page which handles file uploads in my web app.  Is there a way I could capture the timeout and log some data about the upload to help me better understand what the problem is?

The logger would look something like this, I just need to attach it to a timeout exception!

```
Private Sub LogTimeoutException(context As HttpContext)
    'Gather the data
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Toal files: {0}", context.Request.Files.Count))
    For Each f As HttpPostedFile In context.Request.Files
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} ({1}): {2}", f.FileName, f.ContentType, f.ContentLength))
    Next

    'Log it
    Dim l As New BitFactory.Logging.FileLogger(context.Server.MapPath("~/timeoutlog.txt"))
    l.LogInfo(sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason why a try catch wouldn't work?

```
Private Sub LogTimeoutException(context As HttpContext)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Try
        //gather the data
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Toal files: {0}", context.Request.Files.Count))
        For Each f As HttpPostedFile In context.Request.Files
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} ({1}): {2}", f.FileName, f.ContentType, f.ContentLength))
        Next
    Catch he As HttpException    
        //Log it
        Dim l As New BitFactory.Logging.FileLogger(context.Server.MapPath("~/timeoutlog.txt"))
        l.LogInfo(sb.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The exception is not thrown by the LogTimeoutException method, it's thrown somewhere in the ashx page when the built in timeout limits are hit (90 seconds).

Comment: just catch the same HttpException in the body of your ashx page. Do the logging from there.

Comment: OK, I have a handler set in the ASHX page for the logging, now how do I test it?  Any good way to simulate a request timeout?

Comment: You can lower the page timeout with Server.ScriptTimeout down to a couple minutes. Then use Thread.Sleep(x) where x is the number of seconds till a timeout.